# É possível votar para fechar a própria pergunta mesmo sem pontos suficientes?

Tags: suporte, perguntas-duplicadas, fechamento, reputação

Acabei de sinalizar [esta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97882/como-restringir-o-acesso-externo-a-arquivos-pela-url-com-htaccess) minha pergunta como duplicata [desta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/99098/como-prevenir-acesso-direto-ao-meu-c%C3%B3digo-php) (porque mesmo a minha sendo anterior, a outra já recebeu 3 respostas -  inclusive a resposta que eu pensava em fazer na minha, acabei fazendo nesta - então acho que faz mais sentido transformar a minha em duplicata)...

Mas como ia dizendo, ao sinalizar, acabei clicando meio sem ver o que o botão dizia e, quando vi, **eu tinha votado para fechar a minha pergunta.**

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Mas a reputação para votar pra fechar é 3k, não? Então fiquei na dúvida se é um bug, ou se quando a pergunta é nossa, podemos  sempre votar pra fechar.

Comment: Não sei muito bem o comportamento do sistema para casos assim, mas enquanto tentamos entender atendi seu pedido e fechei ela como duplicada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A partir de [250 pontos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) é possível *votar* para fechar e *visualizar* os votos para fechar *na própria pergunta*:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>